# Can I encrypt posgresql column after I created it?

Tags: postgresql, encryption, password-encryption

I have a big (300+ rows) password column and I forgot to encrypt it.

How can I encrypt it now? (in psql)
Or which is the best way to encrypt it?

Comment: Passwords should never be encrypted, they should be salted and hashed with an algorithm made for that purpose. Typically, passwords are hashed at least 1000 times with at least SHA1

Comment: Your question is missing some information and your approach is not good but maybe now you can use [bcrypt](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/pgcrypto.html) -> for example: `UPDATE table SET password = crypt('password',gen_salt('bf'))`

Comment: Sorry I try to correcting now. So I have a column, with passwords without encryptions.
I want to encrypt all of them at once but I dont know how can I do it.
I know this update, but I dont want to do it one by one.

Comment: 1) 300 rows is not big. 2) You will have to do it one by one.  The  solution from @kunsterD93 will do this in one statement, but it will update the rows one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you provided in the question, this should help you for now:

```
UPDATE 
  table_name 
SET 
  password = crypt('password',gen_salt('bf'))
```